# Some websites are blocked from normal browser and it works well in incognito mode

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl some data from a website using python. In initial stages it worked well, but recently it started to block script requests as well as browser from my system. 
I know there will be some blocking mechanism exists for the intended site, but i can browse the same site from incognito mode without any issue.

How can I fix this one? I tried with some header values used in the incognito browser, but no results.

Any help appreciated.

Adding the tried header values for refernce

> "Accept":"*/*", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
>   "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.8", "Cache-Control":"no-cache",
>   "Connection":"keep-alive", "Content-Length":"8",
>   "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
>   "Cookie":"JSESSIONID=6+b5vN7wfvBUHfQOK0d7bls;
>   TS01747e58=01d69c8eb5156bae15c47b3d2578bc88361c69fb48d9ec815b7e3e48aaab4afb974a4d8f5b448e558bfcd1da01f6246b460e8d88a2f87a126f095a23ccdd3d50439c61ecc9;
>   BIGipServerjboss=759271946.20480.0000;
>   TS011968e6_28=01fabe97068921f1b57e70731e79cb34f9d73bcf98d7d1f65c7eb46ba87d3e6e751dec2ee2109c7bc65b7e3cdb05d397b47bdaf21e;
>   TS011968e6=01d69c8eb5a3b1ea223ea72b0b4ace9a0ac39268b9d9ec815b7e3e48aaab4afb974a4d8f5b4d619ddc6882f5ecbd3007321d57f557b77bb39ff7ab95e2310bfa4be41364ef",
>   "Host":"abc.co.in", "Origin":"https://abc.co.in", "Pragma":"no-cache",
>   "Referer":"https://abc.jsp", "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux
>   x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116
>   Safari/537.36", "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest",
>   "X-TS-AJAX-Request":"true",

Answer (score 5):

If it is working on `incognito mode`, the problem is more likely referred to cookies.

If it is ok with what you are trying to crawl, try specifying this in your `settings.py`:

```
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
```

Comment: its worked in browser, but still not working with script.

Comment: added "Cookies-Enabled" : "false" with header

Comment: I'm using below code for requesting to the url
result = requests.post(SOURCE_URL, data=data, headers=payload)

Comment: maybe I didn't explain myself, I meant to use that inside your `settings.py` file, on your scrapy project. That tells scrapy to not use cookies for the requests, which means that it won't keep passing sessions IDs and other things.

Comment: Okay, I understand. But in my case its a django application using the scrapy like technique and I added it to the setings.py file but no results

Comment: please check the [scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) on how to pass settings when running scrapy like a script.